# .vimrc mapping for control key not working

Tags: vim

I have the below mapping in my .vimrc for mapping control key + 1, 2, 3.. for switching tabs. I am using gnome terminal in ubuntu 11.10, the control key mappings does not seem to work. could any one tell what I am doing wrong.

VIM - Vi IMproved version 7.3.154

```
map <C-S-]> gt
map <C-S-[> gT
map <C-1> 1gt
map <C-2> 2gt
map <C-3> 3gt
map <C-4> 4gt
map <C-5> 5gt
map <C-6> 6gt
map <C-7> 7gt
map <C-8> 8gt
map <C-9> 9gt
map <C-0> :tablast<CR>
syntax on
set shiftwidth=2
```

Comment: Check in `Edit > Keyboard shortucts` in Gnome Terminal if that combinations of keys are already mapped to something. I think they're for tab-switching by default...

Comment: the following suggestion isn't an answer, but bear in mind some suggest to use the lead character rather than the control key

Comment: [How to do it in Xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631241).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First ensure that your terminal emulator (*Gnome Terminal*) doesn't swallow the key combinations for its own functionality; by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + number switches tabs. But I'm afraid you still won't be able to use all those combinations...

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: how can you determine which are used and which are not used?

Comment: Yes that was my issue. Thanks. Is there a way to make terminal NOT swallow those keystrokes?

Comment: @aderchox You can de-configure the default keys: _Edit > Preferences > /Shortcuts\ > Switch to Tab 1: Disabled_